# How does the walker class in Wordpress work?

Tags: wordpress

Does anybody understand how the walker class in Wordpress works? What is it? How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good place to start: [Function Reference/Walker Class « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class)

Comment: care to explain it more ? in more spesific study case or based your own implementation ?

Comment: I haven't actually used it, but the Wordpress docs, as well as the Wordpress forums are always good places to look for Wordpress specific questions (even though there are many here on SO): http://wordpress.org/search/walker+class?forums=1

Answer (score 2):

It walks a tree structure in a database, for example, the Category hierarchy and spits out HTML that represents it.

Look in `wordpress/wp-include/classes.php` at the `Walker_Category` class for an example.